# Are there commercial/freeware/script systems that could back up (daily/weekly/monthly) to S3?

Tags: centos, rhel, backup, amazon-s3

I used to backup 10 important machines (CentOS/RHEL) using `rsnap` to physical HDDs.
I'd like to migrate this backup so its target would be an AWS/S3 bucket.

**Do I have to reinvent the wheel, or are there commercial/freeware/script systems that could back up (daily/weekly/monthly) to S3?**

Comment: Rsync based snapshot tools such as rsnap are going to rely on hard links, which S3 doesn't have. If the machines are already in AWS, use EBS snapshots.

Comment: Thanks, @jordanm - but the machines to be backed up are still physical machines.

Comment: Veeam has a family of products that will do this. "Veeam Free Agent for Linux" is proprietary but free to use, and will backup to (some?) S3 storage systems

Comment: There's also `rsnapshot` to S3-based fuse filesystems such as S3QL and S3FS